# GoLang Redis : Map & Slice

Tags: json, go, redis

I'm using GoLang to get a data from redis hash and then map into a struct.

```
type Person struct {
    ID         string       `json:"id"`
    FirstName  string       `json:"firstName"`
    LastName   string       `json:"lastName"`
    Filters    interface{}  `json:"filters"`
    Type       string       `json:"type"`
}
```

In Redis, a hash field contains a stringified JSON.

> HGET hashname fieldname

Above returns a stringified JSON.

Now "filters" key can be array or map based on the type (That's why I defined Filters type as interface in struct).
I marshall the JSON like below:

```
var p Person
content, err := redis.HGet("hashName", "id").Result()
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(content), &p)
```

Now I have to loop over filters like below but this is giving error that ***cannot range over p.Filters (type interface {})*** (I understand why this error is coming)

```
for _, filter := range p.Filters {
  fmt.Println(filter)
}
```

Is there any way we can handle this situation?

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: Are you asking how to convert JSON text to Go values where an element of the JSON can be an array or object? If so, give examples of the two variants of the JSON.  Redis seems to be unrelated to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `Filters` type `interface{}` into the expected slice. If you don't really know what type it will be, you can use `map[string]interface{}`. Therefore change your `Filters` type to `map[string]interface{}`.

**Per more information**
If `Filters` can be an array (or not), then you might consider a `type switch`:

A simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i interface{}
    //json.Unmarshal([]byte(`["hi"]`), &i)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"a":"hi"}`), &i)

    switch i.(type) {
    case []interface{}:
        println("ARRAY")
    case map[string]interface{}:
        println("NOT ARRAY")
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", i)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use map[string]interface{} then I cannot assign array to Filters. (Filters can be array or map)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I could help.